# How robust is SkPicture?

Tags: 2d, skia

In Skia, if I record something into an SkPicture, is all necessary memory guaranteed to be preserved? i.e.

```
picture_canvas = picture.beginRecording(width, height);
picture_canvas->drawBitmap(*some_bitmap, 0, 0);
delete some_bitmap;
picture.endRecording();
some_canvas.drawPicture(picture); // will this crash since I deleted some_bitmap?
```

Is there any scenario where I could delete something that causes drawPicture() to crash, or is it always guaranteed to work?